# I am trying to find the retirement date from joining date at the age of 58 years in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to find the retirement date from joining date at the age of 58 years in php.

```
    $retire_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($joining_date. '+58 years'));
```

it's showing 1970-01-01 , Up to "+40 years" it's showing correctly.can anyone contribute to find this one

Comment: Please share `$joining_date`

Comment: explain in details and what issue you face

Comment: i have solved it,  if you interest to see my code please reply i will post the code THANK YOU For your contribution friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The valid range of a timestamp is typically from **Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54** UTC to **Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC**. (These are the dates that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed integer.) Additionally, not all platforms support negative timestamps, therefore your date range may be limited to no earlier than the Unix epoch. This means that e.g. dates prior to Jan 1, 1970 will not work on Windows, some Linux distributions, and a few other operating systems. PHP 5.1.0 and newer versions overcome this limitation though.

For **64-bit versions of PHP**, the valid range of a timestamp is effectively infinite, as 64 bits can represent approximately 293 billion years in either direction.

If the number of the year is specified in a two digit format, the values between 00-69 are mapped to 2000-2069 and 70-99 to 1970-1999. See the notes below for possible differences on 32bit systems (possible dates might end on 2038-01-19 03:14:07).

[Source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-notes)

Answer (score 1):

Beside of autista_z's answer,
you can stumple upon this if you use an incorrect date format or something like this

below an example

```
$joining_date = "1976-14-02";
$timeToAdd = "+ 58 years";

$objDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d",$joining_date);
$objDateTime->modify($timeToAdd);
echo "My Retire Date is ".$objDateTime->format("Y-m-d")."<br />";


$retire_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($joining_date.$timeToAdd));
echo $retire_date;
die;
```

This leads with strtotime to a result like 1970-01-01.

This is also the reason why i prefer the Datetime function `createFromFormat` if you know your format, because the outcome is absolutely predictable.

(in this particulary example you'll see - datetime tries to find a correct value and interprets it as 1977-02-02)

Although it doesn't really explain why +40 years would work, but maybe you tested it with different data.

Answer (score 1):

```
$retire_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+58 years', strtotime($joining_date)));
```

**Correct answer**

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you.
`$retire_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+58 years', strtotime($joining_date)));`